# ODI is not detecting csv file in localhost

Tags: sql, oracle, etl, oracle-data-integrator, oracle-fusion-middleware

I'm new to ODI & trying to create my first mapping between csv file and database table. Getting below error when selecting resource name in the data store.

`The directory XXXX specified in your schema does not exist`

I verified that the directory provided in physical schema is correct. **The file is placed in local machine where ODI is also installed.**

I placed my file in different paths, nothing works.

Comment: We need more details : Which operating system? Which version of ODI? What do you mean by `data source` : Data Server, Physical Schema, Model, Data Store? Does the OS user running ODI have permissions to read from this folder?

Comment: Installed ODI 12c in windows 7 OS. In the Resource Name field of the Data Store when I select the file that I want to read, I get this error - The directory XXXX specified in your schema does not exist. Yes , the OS user running ODI have permissions to read the folder

Answer (score 0):

Physical schema should only read C:\xxx\yyy

Earlier I gave the full path including the file name in physical Schema (like C:\xxx\yyy\zzz.csv) which caused the error.

The datastore that you create in the relative model will be called zzz.csv